# Personal domain names?

Tags: domains

As a CompSci student, I felt it was appropriate to create a personal website.

It appears I'm a tad late to this domain name game. My Surname.com/co.uk/me.uk/net/org/name/info/me are all taken. My full name is also taken in these domains.

What options do I have? I don't like the idea of mis-spellings or adding numbers as this leads people to confusion. Would rather not use a ccTLD unless it's for the UK.

first-lastname.co.uk is available? It's 16 characters long including the dash. This seems long for email. Do dashes matter in a domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have your surname as second-level domain, you might want to take a look at the [new gTLDs](http://newgtlds.icann.org/). You’ll probably find a good list at your favorite domain provider.

The obvious alternative: Choose something else. An abbreviation of your name, a nickname, a fantasy name/term, the meaning of your name in a different language, ….

Note that there is a benefit in *not* using your name: Your name *might* change (e.g., after marriage). It would be confusing to keep using that domain after that, but it would be a pity to have to move to another one. A personal domain has the chance to be a stable contact point, as everything else in your life might change (name, telephone, address). So choosing a fantasy term has the benefit that it can’t become "incorrect".

> Do dashes matter in a domain?

Matter in which sense? Technically, there is no difference between the dash or any other character: *all* of them matter in a domain.